# Why does law of attraction work?

Tags: practical-islam, allah, islamic-philosophy

If law of attraction works doesn’t it go against God? By using it you are able to get anything you want as long as you believe you can, even if it’s something bad. It worked on so many people including a relative of mine. Why is that if everything is supposed to be on Allah’s will? How are these people getting everything they want if only Allah has the power to do that and decide what happens?

Comment: There is NO "law" of attraction. Being optimistic certainly does help you succeed towards achieving a specific task (mental readiness), but that doesn't mean you always will.

Answer (score 2):

I want a sandwich.

I believe that if I go into the kitchen, get some bread and cheese from the fridge, I will end up with a sandwich.

Does this go against God?

No.

Does believing that I'll end up with a sandwich mean I'll end up with a sandwich?

No.

Maybe I'm run out of bread. Maybe I'd die of a heart attack on the way to the kitchen. Maybe I'll actually make a sandwich and end up attacked by terrorists who steal it.

If it were Allah's will that I don't get a sandwich, then I wouldn't get a sandwich. Period.

Similarly, the Law of Attraction: Whether it exists or does not exist, it only does so contingent on Allah's will. It's existence does not go against Allah, nor does believing in it.

What *does* go against Allah is the belief that anything — be it the Law of Attraction or anything else of His Creation — can ever succeed in spite of, or especially *against*, Allah's will.